# Not able to run motors using l298n motor driver

Tags: arduino, l298, hc-05

[image]I try to make a gesture controlled robot using L298n, Arduino Uno and bluetooth module HC-05. I send gesture data from a mobile. I have checked there's no problem in the data communication from mobile. But when I try for forward gestures only one motor is working. I have tried 9v battery  but result is same that is not working. This is my program:

```
const int motor1Pin1 = 3;  
const int motor1Pin2 = 4;
const int motor2Pin1 = 10;
const int motor2Pin2 = 11;

byte serialA;

void setup() {

  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // initialize the ledPin as an output:
  pinMode(motor1Pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor1Pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2Pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2Pin2, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

if (Serial.available() > 0) {serialA = Serial.read();Serial.println(serialA);}

      switch (serialA) {

   case 0:
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
      break;

   case 1:
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
      break;

   case 2:
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, HIGH);
      break;

   case 3:
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
      break;

  case 4:
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to add a schematic of how the L298 DUAL FULL-BRIDGE DRIVER is connected between the Ardiuno uno and motors?

Comment: When you mention there is an Allnet bluetooth module *HC-05*, readers of your post don't have to research that.

Comment: The question contains ``But when I try for forward gestures only one motor is working.``. However from the code it isn't clear what the _forward gestures_ are, nor which motor isn't working.

Comment: from code and diagram you can see command 1 is for forward and 2 is for backward and left motor is not working